# PrimeNG p-calendar is automatically set in center of screen

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

I have a problem that the p-calendar is automatically set to the center of the screen after navigating to a page.

Link to YT where I presented the problem: https://youtu.be/igHwGI3GhUo

```html
<mat-grid-tile
  [rowspan]="(isHandset$ | async) ? '1' : '2'"
  *ngIf="offerItem.calendarFlag"
>
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem">Dostępność urządzenia:</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center">
      <p-calendar
        [focusTrap]="false"
        [inline]="true"
        [selectOtherMonths]="true"
        [disabledDates]="disableDates"
        [showWeek]="!(isHandset$ | async)"
      ></p-calendar>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions style="display: block">
      <div class="div-legend" *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)">
        <i class="bi bi-9-circle-fill week"></i>
        <span>Numery tygodni</span>
      </div>
      <div class="div-legend">
        <i class="bi bi-9-circle-fill occupied"></i>
        <span>Termin niedostępny</span>
      </div>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

I looked for solutions, but none helped. I want to achieve that the page does not set the calendar in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the calendar element to be at the start of the page, you can programmatically scroll the page to the top of the screen. It has got nothing to do with primeng. Setting the position of your mat-card should resolve the issue.